# Gwt Compile Permutation size with locales

Tags: gwt, compilation, locale, permutation

In my applicaktion I want to support 2 languages (en,tr) for the same country. So i dont want to have different number/date formats for my application.

Without any locale settings (which means there is only default locale) I have 6 permutations. 
But when I add tr and en my permutations become 18. So still I have the default locale in the picture.

So my first question
   How can I get rid of default locale ( I want my default to be en which i defined)

I need localization just for locale specific messages , just one interface and 2 message properties files.

I dont understand why it should multiply compile permutations just for this 3 files. Is there a way to make compileation faster with preserving locale settings.

It makes more sense to load the mesasges accourding to locale from a servlet as json and implement the interface by that in GWT compile time by extending the message interface and not having lots of permutations.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce compilation time, you can use -localWorker [number of cores]. This will tell GWT to use [number of cores] for the compilation.

In your module descriptor, you add available locales via

```
<extend-property name="locale" values="en_EN"/>
```

To set the default locale use this:

```
<set-property name="locale" value="en_EN" />
```

This should reduce the number of permutations to 12.

Of course you can load the messages depending on your locale. This means, everytime you start your application, the messages are loaded from server. This will take time and the user has to wait. Also it will increase the application size. THe user has to wait longer before your application has loaded and he can start using it.

Personally I would use dynamic loading of messages, if I want to switch the locale without reloading the application or if the messages will be edited often and I don't want to compile the application everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic i18n if you don't want multiple permutations:

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n.html#DevGuideDynamicStringInternationalization

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. 
So the solution to this problem is below. Now total permutations is 6*2=12 instead of 6*3. So defualt locale is disappered.

```
  <extend-property name="locale" values="en,tr"/>
  <set-property-fallback name="locale" value="en"/>

  <set-property name="locale" value="en,tr"/>
```

But I still could not find a way to handle messaging without increasing permutation size.